# Empty User-Agent in Requst creates NPE in legazy API

Tags: java, apache, jboss, request

Is there a good way of setting a user-agent string in a incoming HTTP request within a Java application? I'm using a old library that fails with a nullPointer cased by empty user-agent. The library can not be replaced, and it is not a quick fix to decompile and fix the error in the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a suggestion:
Assuming you are using JBoss as Application-Server,
you could write a ServletFilter to modify the request.

see here:
http://javabeanz.wordpress.com/2009/02/11/how-to-write-a-simple-servlet-filter/

Comment: Seems to be working perfect! Your comment also lead me to http://vangjee.wordpress.com/2009/02/25/how-to-modify-request-headers-in-a-j2ee-web-application/ that's a perfect example to what I wanted to accomplish.